# Outlook Push Notifications REST API - Missed Changetype

Tags: webhooks, office365api

I have implemented calendar syncing with our internal CRM using the Outlook REST (v2) API.  I am using Push Notifications (Webhooks) to push Office 365 calendar changes back into our CRM.

I am seeing a large number of "Missed" notifications. eg

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.Notification",
      "Id": null,
      "SubscriptionId": "xxxxxxx",
      "SubscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2018-11-21T11:12:10Z",
      "SequenceNumber": 1,
      "ChangeType": "Missed"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the basic flow of events:
•   User creates a Calendar event in our CRM
•   This event is created in the Users Outlook calendar
•   A subscription event (https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/{User}/subscriptions) is created for this users calendar to “monitor” any Updated or Deleted actions for these Calendar event.  Any events that have not been created by the CRM are ignored and are not monitored.  I am also not monitoring any Created events.
•   When the user Updates or Deletes a monitored event outlook will call our webhook 
•   When the webhook receives the event it will sync the changed event

However, the "Missed" notifications are generally more than the "Updated" notifications. I am seeing (on average) 150 Missed events and only 50 Updated Events.

Why do we have so many missed events?

How can I debug this to identify why we are getting Missed events?

Thanks.

Comment: A Missed notification occurs when the notifications service cannot send the requested notification. Have you check these links? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations#ChangeType. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320562/what-to-do-if-app-misses-notification-sequencenumber-jumps-over-by-one-or-more.

Comment: Yes I have "A Missed notification occurs when the notifications service cannot send the requested notification."  But why can't it send a notification?  Any Debugging to determine why?  I am getting hundreds more missed then Updated notifications.  If this is the case then webhooks are not very reliable for this service.  I will end up doing delta Syncs constantly.

Comment: I expect the occasional Missed notification, not the hundreds I am seeing.